# Doctrine 2.2 Datetime string conversion in Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am troubleshooting a search bar to return rows within a period chosen from 'To' and 'From' datepickers.

I initially got this error :

> Error: Method Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Comparison::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

I converted the relevant query to a string using ->format() function:

```
            if (is_array($value) && isset($value['to'])) {

            $to = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $value['from'] . ' 23:59:59');
            var_dump($value, $to);die;
            if ($to <> false) {
                $query->andWhere(
                        $query->expr()->lte($path, $to->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                );
            }
        }
```

Now doctrine throws the following error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 977: Error: Expected end of string, got '00'

Is there something else I need to do to format the date to make it acceptable to the querybuilder? I've tried using / instead of : but this causes an issue.

Comment: Try `$to->format('U')`. Does it work ?

Comment: Yes, thanks: that prevents an error but the date is not in a usable format for the db query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you should either use **literal()**, or query parameter. And since the `lte` argument is not constant, using `literal()` is highly discouraged (due to potential SQL injection).

Anyway, something like this should probably work:

if (is_array($value) && isset($value['to'])) {

```
if (is_array($value) && isset($value['to'])) {

    $to = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $value['from'] . ' 23:59:59');

    if ($to <> false) {
        $query->andWhere($query->expr()->lte($path, ':to'));
        $query->setParameter('to', $to->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    }
}
```

Does it work?

Hope it helps...

Comment: You probably now have no need to `createFromFormat`, but it is a valid sanity check of input data...

Comment: Thanks Jovan, no longer getting the error but now getting a 'Expression of type 'Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder' not allowed in this context.'

Comment: Ooouuu darn... silly mistake. Move the ‘$query->setParameter’ call outside of ‘andWhere’ call :-)

Comment: That appears to have fixed it! no more error, but the row from the db is not being returned so I will have to see if I can work out why. Thanks for your help Jovan.

Comment: Wonder why.... can you spot the query in your dev log? That could help narrow down the mistake...

Comment: Don't worry it did work: I just had a toggle unset on the test search!